# Rename a table in all the objects in Azure SQL Server

Tags: azure-synapse

I want to rename a table and it has to rename the table in all the procedures or views wherever that table is been used . How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

There is no inbuilt feature that allows renaming all references of the tables in all SQL definitions.

The best-case scenario can very well be to use your preferred SDK and refactor the code manually.

Answer (score 0):

You need to open the database project via Visual studio and then right click on the selected object and under Refactor select Rename.

[image]

[image]

Click Ok and Then Apply.

This would update all references with the latest names across views and stored procedures.

Once done you can publish the database project to the server.